# How can I easily fill form fields?

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins, autofill

The example ajax form

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="text" name="email" />
  <select name="group">
    <option value="1">group 1</option>
    <option value="2">group 2</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

each time the form is show an ajax call is sent and the server returns a json object like

```
{"name":"john", "email": "john@some-domain.com", "group": 2}
```

I don't want to do the tedious work of filling the form with the json data manually, e.g

```
$('#myform').fillWith( json );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could easily build a simple plugin to do so:

```
jQuery.fn.fillWith = function(input) {
  return this.each(function(){
    var form = this;
    $.each(input, function (key, value) {
      $(form).find('[name='+key+']').val(value);
    });
  });
};
```

You may want to optimize the attribute selector, to check only for `input`, `select`, `textarea` elements, in this example the selector is looking for any element (`*[name=foo]`).

Also you might have to add some code to handle radio buttons correctly.

Check an example with your markup [here](http://jsbin.com/elepo).